# Is there a way to have tmux programmatically load history from a file?

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to set up a tmux session where some of the windows connect to a remote server and attach a screen (tmux isn't installed on the server). Upon attaching the remote screen, I'd like to copy the history of the screen into tmux (I want the history to be persistent, even if the tmux session is restarted).

Is there a way to do that? I didn't see anything obvious while digging through the man pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, the hacky solution I came up with works well enough. I just have screen dump its history to a file, and then cat/delete the file.